# Replace a string in a python script and execute the script

Tags: python, sed

I have a Python script that merges CSV files together. Before I execute the script, I want to replace the a string in the file. I can do that using this sed command -

`sed 's/state/MI/' my_script.py`

How do I pass this to Python for execution? I have tried the below so far -

`python "$(sed 's/state_name/MI/' my_script.py)"`

That doesn't work but when I try the same thing with PSQL it does -

`psql -d db -c "$(sed 's/state_name/MI/' summary.sql)"`

Comment: Is it not possible to send your desired string as an argument to the python file? or are you actively trying to avoid using command line arguments for some reason?

Comment: wouldn't it be more simple to just open the .py file in IDE and make the replacement? That said it may be better to refactor the script (e.g. to take CLI arguments) if this will be required frequently

Comment: @VincePayandeh Thank you. I will use command line arguments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You sound like you know how to use commandline arguments, but just for the sake of completion, for those who read this question in the future and are not sure how to go about using command line arguments with python:

One easy quick way to receive commandline arguments in your code is to use the `argv` property  of the `sys` module which is a list that contains all arguments sent to the script. When a python file is called, the first argument captured by `sys.argv` is the name of the script itself. Any commandline arguments are captured afterwards:

```
import sys
arguments = sys.argv
# make sure user really sent an argument, or else set it to some default value
if len(arguments)>1:
    desired_string = arguments[1]
else:
    desired_string = "Some_default_value"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke commandline programs with [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html)

```py
import subprocess

def func():
    with subprocess.Popen(['sed', 's/state/MI/', "my_script.py"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE) as process:
        stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
    print(stdout)
```